# Find nearest prime number python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to find the largest prime number within `range(old_number + 1 , 2*old_number)`

This is my code so far:

```
def get_nearest_prime(self, old_number):
    for num in range(old_number + 1, 2 * old_number) :
        for i in range(2,num):
            if num % i == 0:

                break

    return num
```

when I call the `get_nearest_prime(13)` 
the correct output should be `23`, while my result was `25`.
Anyone can help me to solve this problem? Help will be appreciated!

Comment: Well, why would `num` ever be anything other than `2*old_number - 1`? There's nothing in your code that would end the loop early. When it finds a prime number, it just moves on to the next number.

Comment: how do I change it so it returns the largest prime number???

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of changes you *could* make, but which ones you *should* make depend on what you want to accomplish. The biggest problem with your code as it stands is that you're successfully identifying primes with the `break` and then not doing anything with that information. Here's a minimal change that does roughly the same thing.

```
def get_nearest_prime(old_number):
    largest_prime = 0
    for num in range(old_number + 1, 2 * old_number) :
        for i in range(2,num):
            if num % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            largest_prime = num
    return largest_prime
```

We're using the `largest_prime` local variable to keep track of all the primes you find (since you iterate through them in increasing order). The `else` clause is triggered any time you exit the inner `for` loop "normally" (i.e., without hitting the `break` clause). In other words, any time you've found a prime.

Here's a slightly faster solution.

```
import numpy as np

def seive(n):
    mask = np.ones(n+1)
    mask[:2] = 0
    for i in range(2, int(n**.5)+1):
        if not mask[i]:
            continue
        mask[i*i::i] = 0
    return np.argwhere(mask)

def get_nearest_prime(old_number):
    try:
        n = np.max(seive(2*old_number-1))
        if n < old_number+1:
            return None
        return n
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

It does roughly the same thing, but it uses an algorithm called the "Sieve of Eratosthenes" to speed up the finding of primes (as opposed to the "trial division" you're using). It isn't the fastest Sieve in the world, but it's reasonably understandable without too many tweaks.

In either case, if you're calling this a bunch of times you'll probably want to keep track of all the primes you've found since computing them is expensive. Caching is easy and flexible in Python, and there are dozens of ways to make that happen if you do need the speed boost.

**Note** that I'm not positive the range you've specified always contains a prime. It very well might, and if it does you can get away with a lot shorter code. Something like the following.

```
def get_nearest_prime(old_number):
    return np.max(seive(2*old_number-1))
```

I don't completely agree with the name you've chosen since the largest prime in that interval is usually not the closest prime to `old_number`, but I think this is what you're looking for anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sublist to check if the number is prime, if `all(i % n for n in range(2, i))` means that number is `prime` due to the fact that all values returned from modulo were `True`, not 0. From there you can `append` those values to a list called `primes` and then take the `max` of that list.

*List comprehension*:

```
num = 13
l = [*range(num, (2*num)+1)]
print(max([i for i in l if all([i % n for n in range(2,i)])]))
```

Expanded:

```
num = 13
l = [*range(num, (2*num)+1)]

primes = []
for i in l:
     if all([i % n for n in range(2, i)]):
        primes.append(i)

print(max(primes))
```

> ```
> 23
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Search for the nearest prime number from above using the **seive** function

```
def get_nearest_prime(old_number):
    return old_number+min(seive(2*old_number-1)-old_number, key=lambda a:a<0)
```